# how to assign different physics to different particle systems?

Tags: particles, physics

I'm trying to set up 2 different particle systems in my animation, one with "wind" blowing the particle system upward, one with a different particle system making a light streak.  The wind blowing the first particle system takes place first, but when I try to set up the light streak particle system, the "wind" for the 1st particle system blows my light streak upward too.  Is there a way to assign different force fields in physics to  particular particle systems?  Thank you!

Comment: I might have figured out the simple solution.  Setting up the "field force settings" in the corresponding "Particle settings" solved the problem :)  If anyone has better ideas, please share.  Thank you!